# SendOrderedBroadcast issue: recevied intent is the sent one

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

When I call the sendOrderedBroadcast method, the Intent passed to the onReceive is exactly the same I am sending.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Action.ACTION);
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent1) {
        String action = intent1.getAction();
        //action is still Action.ACTION
        if(!action.equals(Action.DIFFERENT_ACTION)) {
            return;
        }
        assertEquals(Action.DIFFERENT_ACTION, action);
        Bundle bundle1 = intent1.getExtras();
        assertEquals(bundle1.getString(ExtraConstants.TYPE), ExtraConstants.MONITOR);
    }
}, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

and even returning the bundle with the setResult method does not help. 
Also the intended receiver is able to receive the intent and work with it properly, but I cannot find a way to reply from that receiver. 
Any ideas?

**EDIT-1**

I'm testing my broadcast receiver [let's call it BR1] dynamically registered using robolectric. In this piece of code I'm sending an intent to BR1, and I expect BR1 to set a result to be received by the BroadcastReceiver in the snippet (let's call it BR2). What happens is that the intent sent to BR1 is also received by BR2, which does not get called again

**EDIT-2**
I'm trying the same thing within a standalone Android application, following you can find the code

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("call.br.my");
        this.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("call.br.my");
        intent.putExtra("hello", "ciao");
        sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(intent.getStringExtra("hello") != null) {
                    return;
                }
                log.info(intent.getStringExtra("ciao"));
            }
        }, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
    }
}

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyReceiver.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        log.info(intent.getStringExtra("hello"));
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("ciao", "hello1");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, "ciao", bundle);
    }
}
```

But the string put in the bundle is not received by the BroadcastReceiver declared in the sendOrderedBroadcast which is only able to receive the sent intent.

Comment: "I cannot find a way to reply from that receiver" -- [call `setResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#setResult(int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) or related methods (e.g., `setResultExtras()`).

Comment: I did it, using setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null, bundle), but it doesn't work, should I have to call something else after setResult?

Comment: I don't think so. I have not used this six-parameter `sendOrderedBroadcast()` and tried getting a result. Are you sure your receiver is getting control and its `setResult()` is getting called? Also, you might experiment with passing `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` instead of `Activity.RESULT_OK` in your `sendOrderedBroadcast()` call and see if that has any effect on the results.

Comment: I've edited my questions, there are more details there.

Comment: Toss your code into a scrap Android Studio project and try using it directly, rather than using Robolectric in tests. Or, perhaps try this as an instrumented test. You may be running into a Robolectric limitation or bug.

Answer (score 0):

In the BroadcastReceiver where you get the result you don't use the intent parameter directly but instead must call getResultExtras()

For example in Kotlin:

```
val resultExtras = getResultExtras(true)
```

You can then get whatever bundle/extra data you have set via the resultExtras